# Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content(/description/)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm encountering this error, which i think is because i have a navigation bar placed right on top of my page, hence rspec is detecting for text within the navigation bar.

```
Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content(/description|content/)
       expected to find text matching /description|content/ in "Portal Register Login Please sign in Email Password Remember me Sign up Forgot your password?"
```

What should i write in my rspec test so that i can correctly test if the content is present?

article_spec.rb

```
it 'has a list of articles' do
  article1 = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:article)
  visit articles_path
  expect(page).to have_content(/description/)
end
```

spec/factories/article.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    title "Title 1"
    description "Some description"
    user
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** I use javascript to toggle between tabs of a list of articles on the index page.

index.html.erb

```
<div class = "container">
  <h1 align="center">All Post</h1>
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-9">

      <div id="tabs">   
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li role="presentation" class="active" data-toggle="tab" ><a href="#tab1">Newest</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" data-toggle="tab"><a href="#tab2">Frequent</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"data-toggle="tab"><a href="#tab3">Votes</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
             <% @articles.each do |article| %>
               <%= render 'article', article: article %>
             <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
             <% @articles_views.each do |article_views| %>
               <%= render 'article', article: article_views %>
             <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
             <% @articles_votes.each do |article_votes| %>
               <%= render 'article', article: article_votes %>
             <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div> 
    <div class = "col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
});
</script>
```

_article.html.erb

```
 <h3><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h3>
```

Comment: What's the html tag containing your text?, can you add it? Are you using JS to load them?

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the html for not being authenticated. Depending on your authentication system (like devise) you need to mock the authentication (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs).

Also, a super helpful thing I've used for feature tests was to open the page being rendered (using https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot). This will allow you to see why the text you expect to see on the page is not present

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test whether some content is present on a specific page, you can write a `feature` spec like this:

```
# spec/features/article_management_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature 'Article management', type: :feature do
  given!(:article1) { FactoryGirl.create(:article) }

  scenario 'Page has specific content' do
    visit articles_path
    expect(page).to have_content(/description/)
  end
end
```

If `articles#index` loads the articles by invoking the database like `@articles = Article.all`, then you have to make sure the `articles` table has the test data (`article1` in your case) in place before visiting the path. Thats why you need `FactoryGirl.create(:article)` instead of `build_stubbed`.

#### Prefer `FactoryGirl.create` over `build/build_stubbed` when you want to load data from database to see the expected changes.

From `FactoryGirl` doc:

```
# Returns an article instance that's not saved
article = build(:article)

# Returns an object with all defined attributes stubbed out
stub = build_stubbed(:article)

# Returns a saved article instance
article = create(:article)
```

**Some Aliases to note**:

`feature` is in fact just an alias for `describe ..., type: :feature`, `scenario` for `it`, and `given/given!` aliases for `let/let!`, respectively.